# How to print lines from a file that contain a specific word using java?

Tags: java, java-io, file-handling

How to print lines from a file that contain a specific word using java ?

Want to create a simple utility that allows to find a word in a file and prints the complete line in which given word is present.

I have done this much to count the occurence but don't knoe hoe to print the line containing it...

```
      import java.io.*;

       public class SearchThe {
          public static void main(String args[]) 
           {
             try 
              {
                String stringSearch = "System";

                 BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:/sh/test.txt"));

         int linecount = 0;
            String line;

        System.out.println("Searching for " + stringSearch + " in file...");

        while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)
        {
            linecount++;
            int indexfound = line.indexOf(stringSearch);

            if (indexfound > -1) 
            {
                System.out.println("Word is at position " + indexfound + " on line " + linecount);
            }
        }
        bf.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can use `contains` method from String instance which represents each line. If you want to avoid false positive matches you can use regex with word boundary. Anyway please describe what problem you are having with your code so we could help you solve it.

Comment: what u have tried till now? Some code please...

Comment: Have you been able to read in the file line by line? If yes, why isn't there any code present?

Comment: i am a beginer in java..and also to this site..so don't know how to post a question...but i am willing to work hard and so want to know the various methods to above problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you are reading from a file named file1.txt Then you can use the following code to print all the lines which contains a specific word. And lets say you are searching for the word "foo".

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
    public class Classname
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
        File file =new File("file1.txt");
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(file);
            while(in.hasNext())
            {
                String line=in.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("foo"))
                    System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }}
```

Hope this code helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void grep(Reader inReader, String searchFor) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(inReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(searchFor)) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
   grep(new FileReader("file.txt"), "GrepMe");
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to do something like this

```
   public void readfile(){
     try {

        BufferedReader br;
        String line;

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file path"), "UTF-8");
        br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          if (line.contains("the thing I'm looking for")) {
            //do something 
          }
          //or do this
          if(line.matches("some regular expression")){
            //do something
          }
        }

        // Done with the file
        br.close();
        br = null;

      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

Comment: 1. don't swallow exceptions  
2. your code can leave unclosed resources `br`

Comment: you're right... I left that up to him, but I will make an edit

Comment: would have also been better to use try with resources

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `BufferedReader` or `Scanner` for reading the file.
To check if a String contains a word use `contains` from the `String`-class.

If you show some effort I'm  willing to help you out more.